# async - callback already used error

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm getting a 'callback already used' error and I don't know why. I am using async and want to chain two functions because the second function depends on the first function to complete.

I'm new-ish to Node.js and still wrapping my head around async/callbacks. Thanks so much for helping out.

***getCdn takes in cnames, and if the cname is part of a CDN it pushes the results into a global variable called cdnAttrs.***

```
function getCdn(cnameDict, callback) {
  // cdnAttributes contains associative array with each web attribute: {name_in_db : code_snippet_to_find_in_cname}
  for (var key in cdnAttributes) {
    if (cdnAttributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var snippet = -1;
      // some technologies contain multiple code snippets, in that case they are stored as array. Single code snippets are stored as string
      if (!Array.isArray(cdnAttributes[key])) {
        snippet = cnameDict['cname'].indexOf(cdnAttributes[key])
      }
      else {
        // check each code snippet within the array, if any match the source code, update 'snippet'
        for (var n = 0; n < cdnAttributes[key].length; n++) {
          var val = cnameDict['cname'].indexOf(cdnAttributes[key][n])
          if (val > -1) {
            snippet = val
          }
        }
      }
      // if attribute found in tag, create cdnAttrs[cdn] = [{from: hostname, proof: cname}, {from: hostname2, proof: cname2}, ...]
      if (snippet > -1) {
        try {
          cdnAttrs[key].push(cnameDict);
        }
        catch (e) {
          cdnAttrs[key] = [];
          cdnAttrs[key].push(cnameDict);
        }
        callback();
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }
}
```

***My async function looks like this:***

```
async.series([
  // THIS FUNCTION WORKS FINE... 
  function(callback) {
    async.each(toCheck, function(hostname, callback) {
      getCname(hostname, callback);
    },callback);
  },
  // THIS FUNCTION RETURNS RETURNS Error("Callback was already called.")
  function(callback) {
    async.each(toCheckCnames, function(cnameDict, callback) {
      getCdn(cnameDict, callback);
    },callback);
  }
], function(err){
  if(err) {
    console.log('ERROR');
  }else{
    console.log('toCheckCnames is done: '+JSON.stringify(toCheckCnames));
    console.log('cdnAttrs is done: '+JSON.stringify(cdnAttrs));
  }
})
```

**the getCnames function works:**

```
function getCname(hostname, callback){
  dns.resolve(hostname, 'CNAME', function(error, cname) {
    if (cname) {
      toCheckCnames.push({from: hostname, cname: cname[0]});
        callback();
      }
    // if not CNAMEd, check SOA on www.domain.com and domain.com
    else {
      if (hostname.slice(0,4) == 'www.') {
        hostname = hostname.slice(4);
      }
      nativedns.resolve(hostname, 'SOA', function(error, records) {
        if(!error && records) {
          toCheckCnames.push({from: hostname, cname: records[0]['primary']});
          callback();
        }
        else if (!error) {
          hostname = 'www.'+ hostname
          nativedns.resolve(hostname, 'SOA', function(error, records) {
            if (!error) {
              toCheckCnames.push({from: hostname, cname: records[0]['primary']});
              callback();
            }
            else callback()
          });
        }
        else callback()
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getCdn` function is a loop that will call the callback after each iteration.  If calling the callback is intended to stop the loop execution, you can do `return callback()`.  Otherwise you need to reorganize your code to only call the callback once when the function is done.

UPDATE:

You can also simplify your async.each calls:

```
// Was this
async.each(toCheck, function(hostname, callback) {
  getCname(hostname, callback);
},callback);

// Could be this
async.each(toCheck, getCname, callback);
```

Comment: I also added the getCname function as reference. From my understanding, getCname does a callback to async.each. Only after async.each iterated over the entire array, it will do the final callback which makes async.series move on to the next function. What's different between getCname and getCdn that makes getCname work without error, and getCdn throw the callback? Should getCdn make a callback for each iteration to async.each? Where's my disconnect?

Comment: In any of the async methods that use functions, the callback is basically used to say "This function is done processing".  If you come from a blocking language, think of the callback as a return statement.  It's a necessity because of the non-blocking nature of node.  The `getCdn` function calls the callback for every loop, which is wrong because the function isn't actually finished processing in total.  Conversely, the `getCname` function will only call the callback once, rightly when it is done working.

Comment: To get used to the callbacks, you could change your lines that just read `callback()` to read `return callback()`.  That'll give you an idea of what it should be doing.  If your code still works then you're using callbacks correctly!